# Trying to get file paths to work across all releases in Java/Netbeans

Tags: java, file, netbeans, file-io, io

So I'm working on a game, and I need help with my file i/o for savefiles. Currently I have something like this setup to read from them:

```
public static void savesManagementMenu() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        fileURL = JRPG.class.getResource("Saves/save" + i + ".txt");
        System.out.println(fileURL);
        if (fileURL != null) {
            saveMenuSaveFile = new File(fileURL.getPath());

            try {
                //System.out.println("File # " + i +" exists.");
                saveMenuSaveFileReader = new FileReader(fileURL.getPath());
                saveMenuFileScanner = new Scanner(saveMenuSaveFileReader);

                saveMenuInfo[i - 1][0] = saveMenuFileScanner.nextLine();
                saveMenuFileScanner.nextLine();
                saveMenuFileScanner.nextLine();
                saveMenuFileScanner.nextLine();
                saveMenuInfo[i - 1][1] = saveMenuFileScanner.nextLine();
                saveMenuInfo[i - 1][2] = saveMenuFileScanner.nextLine();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JRPG.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            saveMenuInfo[i - 1][0] = null;
        }
    }...
```

And running/compiling using this method from Netbeans will make the application/game look in "E:\Copy\JRPG\build\classes\jrpg\Saves."

When I clean and build the project, and try to run it via the command line I get a response like this:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/New%20folder/JRPG.jar!/jrpg/Saves/save1.txt
```

Aug 22, 2013 11:54:18 PM jrpg.JRPG savesManagementMenu
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\New%20folder\JRPG.jar
!\jrpg\Saves\save1.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
incorrect)

And the game just freezes up. The file path for the saves that I want it to look into when I run the compiled code is: C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\New folder\Saves

Which would be the relative file path right? How can I fix this problem so that my compiled code looks in the correct location no matter where I run the file from? (Lets say my friend wanted to run the game from his computer except he put the "New Folder" folder somwhere other than his desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A embedded resource is not a `File` and can't be treated as one.  Also, as far as output files, you shouldn't be trying to save inside your application anyway...

Instead, either save the file to the relative location of your application...

```
File saveMenuSaveFile = new File("./Saves/save" + i + ".txt");
```

Or to the users home directory...

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
File saveMenuSaveFile = new File(userHome + "/.YouApplicationName/Saves/save" + i + ".txt");
```